# better pull request manager for azure dev ops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I am using Pull Request Manager Hub from the marketplace for our azure dev ops projects/repos. id like something that has a cleaner UI. It seems too busy and like everything is a button and some of the icons don't show up completely. I don't want to complain too much but is anyone using something else that they like more? My main requirement is that I should be able to see all pull requests across repositories in the same project.

Comment: Tool recommendation requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Jeyenne Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: @DanielMann, I didn't realize that, but now that people have tried to answer it I'm not allowed to delete it. For those who are curious,https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for this question.

Answer (score 5):

I’m the creator of Pull Request Manager Hub and new improvements (better UI, lots of new features) have been released to address some of the main complains. Also, feel free to open issues in the GitHub repo where we try to fix as soon as possible.

Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> My main requirement is that I should be able to see all pull requests
>   across repositories in the same project.

For this demand , you can use [Pull Request Search](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.pull-request-search) extension. This extension allows pull requests to be filtered by status, creator, reviewer, title, start date, end date, and **repository**. You can specify different repos in the same project in the **Repo** drop-down list.

[image]

[image]

Another extension [Pull Request Dashboard](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryanstedman.tfs-pullrequest-dashboard) can also view pull requests across all repositories. But it has a flaw, you can only see the pull requests with **active** status.

Answer (score 0):

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mimeo-vs-marketplace.mimeo-active-pull-requests has a plugin called 'All Active Pull Requests' (among others) is the best I have found so far.

Comment: Really thanks for sharing your solution here, if so, would you please accept your solution as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)